# call custom view.phtml on product detail page

Tags: product, template, product-view

I want to call my custom custom view.phtml

I updated `category > custom design` and added below code

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/test.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

test.phtml i called but i see path as

```
frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/test.phtml
```

i want it to be called from current theme folder

Comment: clear cache ..  ....

Comment: it is working but when i enable debug i see "frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/test.phtml" but i want this to be called from current theme

Comment: it may be file permission issue...

Comment: no i am on windows local

Comment: have you check  at frontend\yourpackage\yourtemplate\template\catalog/product/test.phtml

Comment: @AmitBera I think you can write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to chat there are issue with template  file  `test.phtml` path is not properly implemented it Should under

```
frontend\yourpackage\yourtemplate\template\catalog\product\test.phtml
```